# JS script execution at content loaded via AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have some simple code like this:

JS:

```
function load (element, url) {
    element.innerHTML = '';
    fetch(url).then(function (resp) {
    return resp.text();
    }).then(function (content) {
    element.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', content);
    });
}
```

Content of `url` parameter of `load` function:

```
<div>
    <button id="some-button">Execute click!</button>
</div>

<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        document.getElementById('some-button').addEventListener('click', function () {
            alert('Click at button has been executed.');
        });
    });
</script>
```

My question is: Why click event (or any other JS code) does not work? HTML content is loaded, script tag also do, but JS code does not executing. I just want to replace jQuery function load with custom function load described above.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because you create a new button, which has not an event listener attached. `DOMContentLoaded` isn't triggered by the AJAX call.

Comment: Listening for `DOMContentLoaded` event in main page that occurred before the ajax was even made. Will not work the same as jQuery ready does if page is already loaded

Comment: @Teemy But if I remove DOMContentLoaded event, code will still not work, although click event is attached to the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think JS code included like that does not get recognized as JS code. I mean, text containing `<script>` tag is not considered as JS code and not run. Tried the following and it seems to work. Not sure if this solves your requirement, but it might help you understand the issue. Note the usage of `document.createElement('script')`

```html
<div id="content"></div>
<script>
var scr = `document.getElementById('some-button').addEventListener('click', function () {
            alert('Click at button has been executed.');
        });`;
var content = `<div><button id="some-button">Execute click!</button></div>`;

document.getElementById('content').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', content);
var sel = document.createElement('script');
sel.text = scr;
document.getElementById('content').appendChild(sel);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is final working code:

```
fetch(url).then(function (resp) {
                return resp.text();
            }).then(function (body) {
                element.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', body);
                let scripts = element.getElementsByTagName('script');

                for (let scr of scripts) {
                    var scriptContent = scr.innerText;
                    var newScript = document.createElement('script');
                    newScript.text = scriptContent;
                    scr.remove();
                    element.appendChild(newScript);
                }
            });
```